# Python: A constant subtract by elements of a list to return a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, element

I have a list `decay_positions = [0.2, 3, 0.5, 5, 1, 7, 1.5, 8]` and I want a list such that

```
new_position = 2 - decay_positions
```

Essentially I want a new list where its elements are equal to 2 subtracted by elements of `decay_positions`
However when I do:

```
decay_positions = [0.2, 3, 0.5, 5, 1, 7, 1.5, 8]
print(2 - decay_positions)
```

I get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

So I thought maybe if dimensions aren't the same u can subtract. So I did

```
decay_positions = [0.2, 3, 0.5, 5, 1, 7, 1.5, 8]
print([2]*len(decay_positions) - decay_positions)
```

but it still gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'`

despite the fact that `[2]*len(decay_positions)` and `decay_positions` have the same size. So thoughts? Shouldn't element-wise subtraction be quite straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy ftw:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> decay_positions = np.array([0.2, 3, 0.5, 5, 1, 7, 1.5, 8])
>>> 2 - decay_positions
array([ 1.8, -1. ,  1.5, -3. ,  1. , -5. ,  0.5, -6. ])
```

If you for some reason despise numpy, you could always use list comprehensions as a secondary option:

```
>>> [2-dp for dp in [0.2, 3, 0.5, 5, 1, 7, 1.5, 8]]
[1.8, -1, 1.5, -3, 1, -5, 0.5, -6]
```

Comment: ffs so all I had to do was to use numpy

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
decay_positions = [0.2, 3, 0.5, 5, 1, 7, 1.5, 8]
result = [2-t for t in decay_positions]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
decay_positions = [0.2, 3, 0.5, 5, 1, 7, 1.5, 8]
new_decay_positions = [2-pos for pos in decay_positions ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that if you want to modify the list in place you can do

```py
decay_positions = [0.2, 3, 0.5, 5, 1, 7, 1.5, 8]
decay_positions[:] = (2 - it for it in decay_positions)
print(decay_positions)
```